# Using parameters in a Mule app

Tags: java, spring, properties, mule

I've written a custom Java component for a Mule flow. I've followed [these instructions](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Developing+Components) and implemented the *Callable* interface. Also, I need to configure my mule App via properties, so I've followed the approach described [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files).

My problem is that I haven't been able to retrieve the property values from within the component's Java code, i.e. from withing the *onCall()* method. What I need is a simple way to pass some parameters via configuration to my custom mule component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example the property name is configured in abc.properties. In the flow it is set as flow variable and accessed in java component.

Here is the flow

```
<context:property-placeholder location="abc.properties"/>

<flow name="EchoFlow" doc:name="EchoFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP"
        doc:description="Process HTTP requests or responses." />
    <set-variable value="${name.from.config}" variableName="name"
        doc:name="Variable" />
    <component class="TestComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO" message="#[name]" />
</flow>
```

Here is the component

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;

public class TestComponent implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        // This is how you access a property
        String httpMethod = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("http.method", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
        System.out.println("The value of property name is >>>" + httpMethod);

        // This is how you access flow variable
        String name = eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("name");
        System.out.println("The value of property name is >>>" + name);
        return name + " > " + httpMethod;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. After having a look here http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/schemadocs/schemas/mule_xsd/elements/set-variable.html I realized why I got confused. It's a little intricate, but it makes sense: you need a transformer to add a variable (which can be a property/config value) to the message, in order to retrieve it inside the component's Java code : )